# Using tflearn, getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I'm working with tensorflow==2.2.0rc1 and tflearn==0.3.2 and I keep getting the same error when importing:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

Although I import the packages:

```
import tflearn
import tensorflow
```

Comment: Please share the entire error output.

Answer (score 0):

From TFLearn's [documentation](http://tflearn.org/installation/) and your error, it's probably only compatible with Tensorflow < 2, so reinstall tensorflow of version 1.x.
`tensorflow.contrib` was [deprecated](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md) in Tensorflow 2.

Comment: Yeah but I can only install versions 2.* . I've tried and it says: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.* (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0)

Comment: if you're using pip, try `pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.14`